# 3D arrow tail properties

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to use `VectorPlot3D` to plot a vector field with 3D arrows:

```
B1 = 0.0005;  (*G/μm*)
B2 = -2*B1;
b[x_, y_, z_, Bf_] := {B1*x, B1*y, B2*z + Bf};

VectorPlot3D[b[x, y, z, 0], {x, -13, 13}, {y, -13, 13}, {z, -13, 13}, 
             PlotRange -> {{-13, 13}, {-13, 13}, {-13, 13}}, 
             VectorScale -> {0.1, 1, None}, VectorPoints -> {6, 6, 5}, 
             VectorStyle -> {"Arrow3D", Red}, 
             RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2 < 13^2], 
             Boxed -> True, Axes -> False]
```

Is there a way to change the properties of the 3D arrow tails?  For example, to make them thicker.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `Tube[]` function, but I cannot quite figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

The answer comes directly from the help of [`VectorPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) under *Options* -> *VectorStyle*. There, it is shown how you can use customized graphics to tweak the appearance

```
g = {Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.5]], 
   Graphics3D[Cone[{{-0.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}}, 0.5]]};

VectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> Hue, VectorPoints -> 4, VectorStyle -> {g}, 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.3]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

You can always adjust the `Tube` directives in your final 3d graphics. For this, use a simple replacement, where you fix the tube radius. If `gr` is your graphics, the general approach looks like this:

```
gr /. Tube[pts_, r_] :> Tube[pts, r*scale]
```

To try it, you could include it into a dynamic `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 gr = VectorPlot3D[
   b[x, y, z, 0], {x, -13, 13}, {y, -13, 13}, {z, -13, 13}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-13, 13}, {-13, 13}, {-13, 13}}, 
   VectorPoints -> {6, 6, 5}, VectorStyle -> {"Arrow3D", Red}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2 < 13^2], 
   Boxed -> True, Axes -> False];
 gr /. Tube[pts_, r_] :> Tube[pts, r*scale],
 {{scale, 1}, 0, 2}
]
```

Comment: Thanks Halirutan, what worked for me in the end was to *not* use the cylinder part, and just use a combination of scaling the cylinder and the rest of the vector to get the desired ration between tail and arrow.   But it seems that there is no simple and easy way to just change the size of the tail?

Comment: @MichaelRay A direct way is to replace the `Tube` directives. I gave an example in the update part of my answer. I hope this helps.