# How to hide arrow tail in VectorPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot arrow head only, because I want to plot a "surface" consist of all arrow head(draw a little ball or point instead of real arrow head,because a 'surface' with real arrow head is terrible...).
So is there any way to hide arrow tail or make them transparent?

I've seen a [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/3d-arrow-tail-properties/28803#28803) which use the vector style "Arrow3D", but I don't want the "Arrow3D" style...
[image] that

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, here is what I will do:

I will the take [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) example:

```
g = {Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.5]], 
   Graphics3D[Cone[{{-0.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}}, 0.5]]};
v = VectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   VectorStyle -> {g}, VectorScale -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.3]}, 
   VectorPoints -> 4];
```

Now:

```
v /. {{x_, y_, Graphics3D[Cylinder[z__]]} :> {0, y, 
    Graphics3D[Cylinder[z]]}, Tube[k_, r_] :> Tube[k, 0]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some tail traces can still be seen, but barely.

```
h = Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .1]}];
q = VectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
                 PlotRange -> All, VectorPoints -> 2];
GraphicsRow[{q, 
             q /. Arrowheads[__] :> Arrowheads[{{.5, 1, {h, 0}}}] /. 
                       Arrow[a_] :> Sequence[Opacity[0], Thickness[0], Transparent, Arrow[a]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]